# Macro for Intelligent Transpose

Tags: vba, excel

So currently, per the title, I'm looking to make a smart and relatively automatic transpose system.

So far the only way I've figured out how to do this is with macros, paste special, and a lot of manual work (working on 2,000~ row sheet).

The following example is an example.
All the events belong to A1 but are distributed downwards in a new row. The goal is to have them all in a single row (either in a single cell or adjacent).

```
A       Event 1
A       Event 2
A       Event 3
B       Group 1
B       Group 2
```

All the events belong to A1 but are distributed downwards in a new row. The goal is to have them all in a single row (either in a single cell or adjacent).
The example of how I need them is demonstrate below.

```
A       Event 1 Event 2 Event 3
B       Group 1 Group 2
```

I have searched far and wide and haven't found anything which solves this bizarre request.

Comment: If this would be for a single file, power query would be able to do that (assuming that the a/b categorization is in one column and the event names in another). If looking at repeated use and/or a different file. Perhaps a macro which selects the data and creates a PQ? I haven't really gone that far before, so I'm not sure how generalized you could make it... **Note:** If you're looking for someone to do all the work for you, this is not the site for you.

Comment: Have a look at that answer I gave at [*Combining consecutive values in a column with the help of VBA*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48439700/3219613) the task is pretty similar and can easily be adapted to yours. Otherwise please read http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this quite easily using a dictionary. Have a look at the following. You will need to update the two `With` blocks with your input and destination range

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim arr As Variant, tmp As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim key

    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    ' Source Data
    With Sheet1
        arr = .Range(.Cells(1, "A"), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row, "B")).Value2
    End With

    For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
        If Not IsEmpty(tmp) Then Erase tmp
        If dict.exists(arr(i, 1)) Then
            tmp = dict(arr(i, 1))
            ReDim Preserve tmp(LBound(tmp) To UBound(tmp) + 1)
            tmp(UBound(tmp)) = arr(i, 2)
            dict(arr(i, 1)) = tmp
        Else
            ReDim tmp(0)
            tmp(LBound(tmp)) = arr(i, 2)
            dict.Add key:=arr(i, 1), Item:=tmp
        End If
    Next i

    ' Destination
    With Sheet1.Cells(1, 5)
        i = 0
        For Each key In dict.keys
            .Offset(i, 0) = key
            '' Side by side
            Range(.Offset(i, 1), .Offset(i, UBound(dict(key)) + 1)).Value2 = dict(key)
            '' In one cell
            '.Offset(i, 1).Value2 = Join(dict(key), ",")
            i = i + 1
        Next key
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Say we have data in columns **A** and **B** like:

[image]

Running this code:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim Na As Long, Nd As Long, rc As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, K As Long
    Dim v As Variant

    Range("A:A").Copy Range("D:D")
    Range("D:D").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo

    rc = Rows.Count
    K = 5
    Na = Cells(rc, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Nd = Cells(rc, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To Nd
        v = Cells(i, "D")
        For j = 1 To Na
            If v = Cells(j, 1) Then
                Cells(i, K) = Cells(j, 2)
                K = K + 1
            End If
        Next j
        K = 5
    Next i
End Sub
```

will produce:

[image]